Directus is not connecting with mysql over SSH server
I can't connect my directus project with mysql server.
Getting connection refused error.
However when I'm running this command, I'm able to connect: mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
My docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'
services:
 directus:
  container_name: directus
  image: directus/directus:latest
  ports:
    - 8055:8055
  environment:
   KEY: 'KEY_VALUE'
   SECRET: 'SECRET_VALUE'
   DB_CLIENT: 'mysql'
   DB_HOST: 'localhost'
   DB_PORT: '3306'
   DB_DATABASE: 'directus'
   DB_USER: 'root'
   DB_PASSWORD: 'MYSQL_PASSWORD'
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'MYSQL_PASSWORD'
   MYSQL_USER: 'root'
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'MYSQL_PASSWORD'
   MYSQL_DATABASE: 'directus'
   ADMIN_EMAIL: 'admin@admin.com'
   ADMIN_PASSWORD: 'admin'
 networks:
  directus:


I actually faced the same issue and after terrible search finally I made the solution.
You can connect to mysql by using this modified code:
version: '3.8'
services:
 mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: mysql
  restart: always
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'MYSQL_PASSWORD'
   MYSQL_DATABASE: 'directus'
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"

 directus:
  image: directus/directus:latest
  container_name: directus
  restart: always
  ports:
   - "8055:8055"
  environment:
   KEY: 'KEY_VALUE'
   SECRET: 'SECRET_VALUE'
   DB_CLIENT: 'mysql'
   DB_HOST: 'mysql'
   DB_PORT: '3306'
   DB_DATABASE: 'directus'
   DB_USER: 'root'
   DB_PASSWORD: 'MYSQL_PASSWORD'
   ADMIN_EMAIL: 'admin@admin.com'
   ADMIN_PASSWORD: 'admin'
  depends_on:
   - mysql

networks:
 default:
  name: directus_network


You just shared your password, key and secret with the world. Please invalidate and change them ASAP.

the edit you made is still visible in the history...
